# Squash TM - bugtracker in frame

Tags: mantis, squash

I'm using squashTM in my work and I want to open bug bugtracker (mantis) which I defined in squash options (there is an option in squash to do that). When I'm opening it in new window everything is correct but in frame I've got an error:

```
Load denied by X-Frame options: <mantis_main_page_url> does not permit framing
```

I have this error both in Firefox and IE. What can be wrong? I looked into mantis main page source code but don't know what search and optionally change. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MatisBT by default disallows framing, and this is not configurable. You can patch your installation by commenting out the following line in core/http_api.php:

```
            header( 'X-Frame-Options: DENY' );
```

The bug tracking making this setting configurable is [12165: Allow mantis to be loaded in an iframe](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=12165).

Comment: Now it works nice :) I changed 'X-Frame-Options: DENY' to 'X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM <mantis_url>'. Many thanks!

Comment: @caro2 - glad it helped. Please mark the answer as accepted and vote it up, so others know it's useful.